# How I can Embed CEA-608/708 into videos using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, closed-captions

I'm trying to add CEA-608/708 into different video containers using ffmpeg. I have found out that ffmpeg will not support either of them,is there any other API to do this. I don't want web app or software i Want to do with API

Comment: Check bento4 and GPAC projects, they may have something.

Comment: The only tool I know for encoding 608 is libcaption. It has some bugs, but it works.